# Useful question titles

Tags: discussion, question-titles

I am not usually one to complain about a lack of rules on this site. But, in the interest of keeping the rules as evenly involute as possible, why are there no rules against choosing extremely poor question titles--titles which give no clue as to what the question is actually about?

Examples:

[Haftora for a wedding](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11972/haftora-for-a-wedding)

[Adir Hu - mi yodeya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15409/adir-hu-mi-yodeya)

[So should be done unto the man](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15057/so-should-be-done-unto-the-man)

[Mental Telepathy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53505/mental-telepathy)

Comment: Related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/203/should-vague-titles-be-clarified?rq=1

Comment: ^Not a duplicate because I'm talking about site rules rather than editorial practice

Comment: I don't understand the distinction between "site rules" and "editorial practice."

Answer (score 7):

I [absolutely agree](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52657/where-in-avnei-nezer-can-i-find-this-statement-about-shabbos#comment138606_52657) that clear titles are a must, and have [edited them myself](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/52657/revisions) for clarity...though I was [once reluctant to do so](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19527326#19527326), I am no longer. You have editing privileges; go forth and edit :)

> [...] I don't like editing people's titles, generally, but this one
>   (and some other from the same author) just really rubbed me the wrong
>   way. How am I supposed to know what the question is about from his
>   titles? ~ Shokhet, [Jan 14 '15](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19527326#19527326), in [V'dibarta Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam)
>
> @Shokhet I actually think titles are one of the more important things
>   to edit -- they're what's on the front page, so if they're unclear or
>   incomprehensible or thoroughly ungrammatical or whatever, and you can
>   figure out what the fix is, please do it. ~Monica Cellio, [Jan 14
>   '15](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19527351#19527351), in [V'dibarta Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam)

Besides for the issue of the front page, mentioned by Monica Cellio, above; there's also the issue of searching for questions. I'll often search questions here for information, or to make sure that a question I'm about to ask hasn't been asked before; accurate and descriptive titles are *extremely* useful in determining whether a question that shows as a search result is relevant to what I'm looking for.

---

I didn't know about the [question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203/should-vague-titles-be-clarified) Scimonster linked to in [his answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3452/5323); that would have made my conclusion about question titles a lot easier.

Answer (score 6):

Who says there are no rules? The meta question you linked to in the comments ([Should vague titles be clarified?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203/should-vague-titles-be-clarified)) has a +8/-0 scored answer that says they should be edited. This seems to be enough to me to say that the community agrees that titles like these are not appreciated and should be avoided *lechatchila*, and edited *b'dieved*.

Answer (score 5):

I believe your question has a very simple answer: Edit the titles yourself! It's hard to come up with good titles, but that's no reason to flag a question. Use your editing privilege to edit titles, and the whole site will be better off. I have myself edited quite a few titles, questions, and posts, and they are always accepted happily.